# HTML File Selector for ipad

Tags: javascript

Just **wanted to open the camera (Take photo or video) option from ipad** when clicking on button () which is currently giving me a popup with three option (Take photo or video, choose from library and browse)...**didn't want to use cordova or any othe plugin**.

Using Javascript with html and css.  (Is it possible ?)

Have already tried cordova plugin and it worked but now required without any plugin.

Comment: Hi Arpit, Welcome to the Stack Overflow Community.   We are not a site that just gives out code.  Please see the guidelines.   `#3. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.` https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  Show the work you have done and you will get a better response from the community.

Answer (score 0):

I have use Cordova in the past and has never treated me well in this case for just accessing the camera I would try this:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
<input type="file" accept="video/*" capture="camera">
```

Comment: Hello Joe,Thanks for the reply...Have already tried the above code,it is also opening the same popup with 3 options in that...but i want directly camera to get opened.